# Check if Checkbox is checked is not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code it's always enter in else
ether that in console return true  [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCTVq.png)

```
if ($('.DEL').prop('checked') == true)
{
    // do a
}        
else
{
    //do b
}
```

Comment: reproduce your problem in snippet

Comment: i need to check if checkbox "checked" or not but is not working

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this Go here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Post the html of  ".Del"

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="DEL" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working code to get if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
if(document.getElementById('Your checkbox ID').checked) {
//a
} else {
//b
}
```

Or this way:

```
if($('#Your checkbox ID').is(':checked'))
   //a  
else
   //b
```

And according to your code:

```
if($('.DEL').is(':checked'))
   //a  
else
   //b
```

Or with the `prop` property:

```
if($('.DEL').prop('checked')) {
  //a
} 
else {
  //b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("true");
    }else{
        alert("false");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code you shared it will only executes once when page loaded. So attach a change event handler and move the code.

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(e) {
    if(this.checked){
        alert("true");
    }else{
        alert("false");
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: in load page and it call back

Comment: problem in conduction  not in call the function

Comment: @PaoaRAed : can you reproduce the behavior in fiddle or snippet?